# Is it possible to "miss" the emission from an observable in this case?

Tags: angular, rxjs

At work, we often use the following pattern to react to certain events in our application.

```
class FooService {
  public doFoo(): void {/* HttpRequest that eventually causes onFoo to emit */}
  public onFoo!: Observable<unknown>;
}

class BarService {
  public doBar(arg: unknown): void {/* HttpRequest that eventually causes onBar to emit */}
  public onBar!: Observable<unknown>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'foo, [foo]',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss'],
})
export class FooComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private fooSubscription: Subscription;
  private barSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private fooService: FooService, private barService: BarService) {
    this.fooSubscription = fooService.onFoo.subscribe(this.handleFoo.bind(this));
    this.barSubscription = barService.onBar.subscribe(this.handleBar.bind(this));

    this.fooService.doFoo();
  }

  public models: unknown;

  
  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.fooSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.barSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private handleFoo(result: unknown) {
    /* Do some work with result, then trigger next request */
    this.barService.doBar(result);
  }

  private handleBar(result: unknown) {
    /* Do actual work with data */
    this.models = result;
  }
}
```

> **Note 1** this is always used as a chain, so `handleBar` would never be called independently and in fact, it's undesired behaviour that it might be triggered because of some unrelated component called `doBar()`.

> **Note 2** I'd rather not touch the services for fear it could break the whole application.

This often causes lots and lots of subscriptions and much boiler plate code. I'd like to replace it with rxjs observable chain and bind data with angulars async pipe. I've come up the following code:

```
constructor(private fooService: FooService, private barService: BarService) {
  this.modelObservable = this.fooService.onFoo.pipe(
    tap((result) => this.handleFoo(result)),
    concatMap(() => this.barService.onBar),
    tap((result) => this.handleBar(result))
  );

  this.fooService.doFoo();
}

private handleFoo(result: unknown) {
  /* bit of validation on result */

  this.barService.doBar();
}

private handleBar(result: unknown):unknown {/* Do actual work with data and return modified data*/}
```

So `modelObservable` would eventually emit the value returned by `handleBar` and the async pipe would take care of subscribing and unsubscribing, so I don't have to.

---

However, I'm skeptical whether this works because the observable chain will call `handleFoo`, which will call `doBar()` *before* actually subscribing to `onBar` in `concatMap`. I don't like to rely on timing or probability here. Can this solution work despite it? Or is it possible to "miss" the emission from `onBar`? Is there any better solution to get a single observable that does the same? Maybe another rxjs operator (haven't used that many yet)? Or is it not possible at all to combine this process into a single observable?

Comment: you can put this `this.barService.doBar();` inside pipe() chain too instead of inside `handleFoo()`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda What would that change? I don't really get where I should put it, feel free to explain in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I like to use observables lazily... If you had a service which looked like:

```ts
class FooService {
  public foo(): Observable<unknown>
}

// When you did `doFoo()`, now you must subscribe
this.fooService.foo().subscribe(this.handleFoo);
```

Then you are "sending the request" and subscribing at the same time.

Luckily your service can be adapted easily, to something similar to this pattern, by using defer:

```ts
constructor(private fooService: FooService, private barService: BarService) {
  const lazyBarService = defer(() => {
    this.barService.doBar();

    return this.barService.onBar;
  });

  this.modelObservable = defer(() => {
    this.fooService.doFoo();

    return this.fooService.onFoo.pipe(
      tap((result) => this.handleFoo(result)),
      concatMap(() => lazyBarService),
      tap((result) => this.handleBar(result))
    );
  }
}

private handleFoo(result: unknown) {
  /* bit of validation on result */
}

private handleBar(result: unknown):unknown {/* Do actual work with data and return modified data*/}
```

This will make sure that you subscribe to each `onFoo`/`onBar` extremely close to `doFoo`/`doBar`, as that executes when someone subscribes to the observable.

I think it should be enough, because that happens synchronously and I'm assuming that `doFoo` sends an asynchronous action. Otherwise you'd have to make something similar but that first subscribes to the source, then performs the action.